# Manually (without pip) install SpaCy module

Tags: python-3.x, spacy, rasa

I cannot use pip nor conda to install SpaCy package. I was wondering if there is a way to 'manually' install it. I.e. download it from github

Comment: You can download a wheel from PyPI in the browser but then you have to do that for all the dependencies too. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Would need it for tokenizing sentences for a chatbot designed on rasa